# pgfplotstable - apply formatting to a range of rows

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm looking to change the formatting (specifically the background color) for a range of rows using pgfplotstable. It is easy enough to do this for one row, e.g. the 6th row, using:

```
every row no 6/.style={
    before row={
        \rowcolor={orange}
    }
}
```

but I would like to be able to apply this operation to, say, rows 1-6, or rows 7-12, etc. Is there any way to do this without writing a separate format for every row involved?

Answer (score 6):

This can be done using a TikZ `/.list` handler. What it does is to supply the same arguments to an array of arguments that are internally passed to a TikZ `foreach` mechanism. You just need to embed the style into a custom style and pass the array to that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,colortbl}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset[
  my row iterator/.style={every row no #1/.style={
    before row={
      \rowcolor{orange}
      }
    }
  },
  my row iterator/.list={0,...,3,6}
    ]{
test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 test6 test7 test8 test9 test10
1     2     6     8     1     2     6     8     1     2     
3     4     7     9     3     4     7     9     3     4     
1     2     6     8     1     2     6     8     1     2     
3     4     7     9     3     4     7     9     3     4     
1     2     6     8     1     2     6     8     1     2     
3     4     7     9     3     4     7     9     3     4     
1     2     6     8     1     2     6     8     1     2     
3     4     7     9     3     4     7     9     3     4     
}
\end{document}
```

[image]